# Most efficient way to sort and sort syntax VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am very new to VBA macros for excel.  This site has been extraordinarily helpful thus far.
I have a macro that adds four column headings after the last column, then fills these columns if a certain criteria is met, that part works fine.  Before the columns can be filled I need to sort the data.  My current method for sorting the data is based off of recording a macro, and changing the needed variables.  I have read that often excel records macros very inefficiently.  I kind of frankensteined this together. The following code works.

```
Sub ineffiecientway()
Dim colltr As String
colltr = Replace(Cells(1, LastColumn).Address(True, False), "$1", "") '<-Input column index, returns column letter
Columns("A:" & colltr).Select
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DSEG").Sort.SortFields.Clear
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DSEG").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("A:A") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:=xlSortNormal
ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DSEG").Sort.SortFields.Add Key:=Range("J:J") _
    , SortOn:=xlSortOnValues, Order:=xlAscending, DataOption:= _
    xlSortTextAsNumbers
With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("DSEG").Sort
    .SetRange Range("A:" & colltr)
    .Header = xlYes
    .MatchCase = False
    .Orientation = xlTopToBottom
    .SortMethod = xlPinYin
    .Apply
End With
```

The code below is what I have been working on, and pulling my hair out. I'm sure I am making a million rookie mistakes.  I think this may all be about syntax for .sort that I am failing at.

Note:

- GCI() is a user defined fucntion that searches for the input in row one and returns the column index
- LastRow() is a user defined function that returns the last row of the column index that is input.
- LastColumn just returns the last used column in row one

  ```
  Sub ThisDoesntWork()
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim rngAll As Range
  Dim Col1 As Long 'for sort key1
  Dim Row1 As Long
  Dim Col2 As Long 'for sort key2
  Dim Row2 As Long
  Dim rng1 As Range
  Dim rng2 As Range
  Dim LastCell As Range

  Set ws = Worksheets("DSEG")
  Set LastCell = ws.Cells(LastRow(LastColumn), LastColumn)
  Col1 = GCI("CDate")
  Row1 = LastRow(Col1)
  Col2 = GCI("Start Time")
  Row2 = LastRow(Col2)


  Set rngAll = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, 1), LastCell)
  Set rng1 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, Col1), ws.Cells(Row1, Col1))
  Set rng2 = ws.Range(ws.Cells(1, Col2), ws.Cells(Row2, Col2))


  MsgBox rng1.Address
  MsgBox rng2.Address
  MsgBox rngAll.Address

  With rngAll
  .Sort key1:=Range(rng1), order1:=xlAscending, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, _
  key2:=.Range(rng2), order2:=xlAscending, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers, _
  Header:=xlYes
  End With
  ```

When I run this code it stops at the ".sort" with the error "Run-time error '1004': Method "Range' of object'_Global' failed
I have also tried with "DataOption1:=xlSortNormal" because I don't believe the first range needs to be sort text as numbers, both cause the same error.
I was trying the above code without setting ranges or "Dim"ing worksheet and thought that setting the ranges prior to running the code would help.
I added MsgBox for the ranges to make sure they are the ranges I want.

- First MsgBox returns $A$1:$A$38061
- Second MsgBox returns $J$1:$J$38061
- Third MsgBox returns $A$1:$S$38061

The first two are the ranges that I want to sort by, the last is the range of all the data I want to sort, these are the correct ranges.

Any advice or help getting this working would be greatly appreciated.  Also, any advice on better posting, because I'm sure a made mistakes on the "Proper posting format" as well.

Edit: Thanks Nanashi, I will not repeat functions, I appreciate the tip.
Thanks Jeeped. The Current region bit cleaned it up a lot.  And it was the .columns that fixed the error (I was trying .range)  Million thanks to you both.  The working code is below.

```
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim Col1 As Long 
Dim Col2 As Long 
Set ws = Worksheets("DSEG")
Col1 = GCI("CDate") 'searches string and returns column index
Col2 = GCI("Start Time") 'searches string and returns column index

With ws.Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Cells
.Sort key1:=.Columns(Col1), order1:=xlAscending, DataOption1:=xlSortNormal, _
      key2:=.Columns(Col2), order2:=xlAscending, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers, Header:=xlYes
End With
```

Comment: Style-wise, don't repeat the usage of your functions. It clutters up the code and worsens readability. Assign `GCI("CDate")` to one variable, for example. The code will clean up considerably afterwards and you'll have an easier time debugging.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically, any region I `.Sort` does not have any fully blank rows or columns breaking up the `.CurrentRegion` so I use that to define the range to be sorted. The `.Cells(1,1).CurrentRegion` is the equivalent of selecting A1 and tapping *Ctrl+A*. It encompasses the *island* of data that expands from A1 until it reaches a fully blank column to the right or a fully blank row down.

```
Sub prettyefficient()
    With Sheets("DSEG").Cells(1, 1).CurrentRegion.Cells
        .Sort Key1:=.Columns(1), Order1:=xlAscending, DataOption1:=xlSortTextAsNumbers, _
              Key2:=.Columns(10), Order2:=xlAscending, DataOption2:=xlSortTextAsNumbers, _
              Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, Header:=xlYes
    End With
End Sub
```

You can use up to three keys (*Key1*, *Key2* & *Key3*) in a single command. If you require more than that, break it into two commands.